# how to extract previous string from matched string in regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would extract a particular string from the matched string using regex.

***IMP QuadroIMP QuadroIMP QuadroIMP QuadroIMP QuadroIMP Quadro
IMP Quadrosdfsdfdsfsdfsd
0000022 DE BERNARDINIS FERNANDO DBRFNN72A03A515E 001468
03-01-1972 12-06-2006
IMP Quadro***

from above para, I need to find where the date is available, upon that I need to extract 2nd and 3rd word from the matched string with single regular expression

```
".*\n(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})" - will result only 

"0000022 DE BERNARDINIS FERNANDO DBRFNN72A03A515E 001468
 03-01-1972 12-06-2006"
```

from the above string how to extract "DE BERNARDINIS" using any **and** condition in with the same regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example data, you might add matching 1+ digits from the start of the string, and then use 2 capturing groups to match the 2nd and the third word.

If there are not always digits at the start of the line, you could use `^\S+` to match 1+ times a non whitespace char instead of `^\d+`

```
^\d+ (\w+) (\w+).*\n(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]+ (\w+) (\w+)` Match 1+ digits, followed by matching 2 times a space and 1+ word chars
- `.*\n` Match any char except a newline until the end of the line, then match a newline
- `(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})` 2 capturing groups matching your date like pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MEvFpI/1)

Comment: Thank you, " ^\d+ (\w+\s\w+).*\n(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) (\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) " its solving my issue. i have gotten in group 1.